# How to use MongoDB GeoSpatial Index in C++

Tags: c++, mongodb, geospatial, mongo-cxx-driver

In python, pymongo provides nice support for MongoDB GeoSpatial index. However, for C++ when I use mongocxx in C++, I am a little bit confused about the grammar.

For example, in python (pymongo) I used

```
cursor = db.colection.find(
    {
        "loc": {
            "$near": [lon, lat]
        }
    }
).limit(10)
```

to get nearest 10 items for given location. But how can I do the same thing in C++?

I tried:

```
mongocxx::cursor cursor = coll.find(document{} << "loc" << open_document <<
                                    "$near" << [lon, lat]
                                    << close_document << finalize);
```

I am not sure if this is correct approach, and I failed to set the number of results.

Could anyone give me some instructions on GeoSpatial index in C++? Documents/examples will be highly apreciated.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`mongocxx::options::find::limit`](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-cxx-driver/api/mongocxx-v3/classmongocxx_1_1options_1_1find.html#a50acf6a2aa55d552248cad1b825f014e). Check also [`mongocxx::collection::find`](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-cxx-driver/api/mongocxx-v3/classmongocxx_1_1collection.html#ae3748d404ee8affee0103e75a276abe4). The following should work :

```
mongocxx::options::find opts;
opts.limit(10);

mongocxx::cursor cursor = coll.find(document{} << "loc" << open_document 
    << "$near" << bsoncxx::builder::stream::open_array 
    << lon << lat << bsoncxx::builder::stream::close_array 
    << close_document << finalize, opts);
```