# Error while using MongoDB GeoSpatial Index in C++

Tags: c++, mongodb, compiler-errors, geospatial

In python, pymongo provides nice support for MongoDB GeoSpatial index. However, for C++ when I use mongocxx in C++, I have been getting an error for this code:

```
mongocxx::options::find opts;
        opts.limit(100);
        double lon=10.495;
        double lat=49.665;

            mongocxx::cursor cursor1= db["All_Points"].find(document{} << "loc" << open_document
            << "$near" << bsoncxx::builder::stream::open_array
            << lon << lat << bsoncxx::builder::stream::close_array
            << close_document << finalize, opts);
for (auto&& doc : cursor1) {
    std::cout << bsoncxx::to_json(doc) << std::endl;

}
```

I have followed the solution provided in [How to use MongoDB GeoSpatial Index in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43243200/how-to-use-mongodb-geospatial-index-in-c) , and it throws me an error while building.

The following is my error:

**error: ‘document’ was not declared in this scope**

Any help is removal of this error and providing solution for geospatial using mongocxx driver is appreciated.

Thank you very much.

Comment: And where is `document` declared in the code snippet you show?

Comment: I was of the understanding that the document is what is coming from bsoncxx::builder::stream::document{};? Please correct me if I am wrong about this.

Comment: Please provide a complete, compilable, block of code, and the complete error message. Otherwise we will all just be guessing. We should be able to copy paste your code into a file and run the compiler and reproduce your error exactly.